# FALSO ERROR DE ENTRADA DUPLICADA MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Al colocar un indice sobre la tabla me sale este error

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `esd`.`sdf` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `index2` (`id` ASC, `periodo` ASC);
```

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database. ERROR 1062: Duplicate entry '45526-201810' for key
>   'index2' SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE `esd`.`sdf`  ADD UNIQUE INDEX
>   `index2` (`id` ASC, `periodo` ASC)

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que es un *falso* error?  Pues no lo es. Te lo dice claro, no puede agregar esa restricción porque hay registros repetidos que combinan `id` y `periodo`, además te dice cuáles son: el id `45526` y el periodo `201810`. Si revisas la tabla verás que hay más de una fila que cumple ese criterio. Antes de agregar índices de unicidad debes revisar si la tabla los aceptará verificando los duplicados sobre las columnas que componen el índice.

Comment: Mira por favor [ask]. Las mayusculas se consideran como que estas gritando. porque decis que el error esta mal?

Comment: Revisa antes de realizar el alter que ambos cambos son únicos en tu tabla.